# Added Springfox Swagger-UI and it's not working, what am I missing?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

Following the instructions here:

http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

I added these dependencies to my project:

```
compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.7.0"
compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.7.0"
```

and configured SpringFox Swagger like this:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

but the Swagger UI seems not to get enabled. I tried:

- http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
- http://localhost:8080/api/swagger-ui.html
- http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs/swagger-ui.html

and all I get is:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Sep 11 09:43:46 BST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported
```

and on the logs I see:

```
2017-09-11 09:54:31.020  WARN 15688 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'GET' not supported
2017-09-11 09:54:31.020  WARN 15688 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
```

http://localhost:8080/swagger-resources returns:

```
[{"name": "default",
  "location": "/v2/api-docs",
  "swaggerVersion": "2.0"}]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have any spring security which could prevent the access?

Comment: @StanislavL: no, I haven't enabled security yet.

Comment: @StanislavL: I added the log errors I'm getting and it's a PageNotFound.

Comment: `@Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).groupName("users-public-api")
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .pathMapping("/")
                .enableUrlTemplating(false);
    }` that's my working config.

Comment: @StanislavL: I tried with that, same error.

Comment: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1672 one more possible reason from the discussion - I ran into this issue because I had endpoints with request mappings that had path variables of this form: /{var}. Turns out that this is an issue for both GET and POST endpoints i.e. GET /{var} and POST /{var} block swagger-ui. Once I made the paths more specific, I got swagger-ui to work.

Comment: @StanislavL: bingo! I commented out my single controller with an action and it started to work.

Comment: @StanislavL: do you want to write that comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Now swagger comes with two version V2 and V3, depends on requirement
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64333853/410439

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I ran into this issue because I had endpoints with request mappings that had path variables of this form: /{var}. Turns out that this is an issue for both GET and POST endpoints i.e. GET /{var} and POST /{var} block swagger-ui. Once I made the paths more specific, I got swagger-ui to work.

Quote from https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1672

When spring finds a simple path with just one variable swagger cannot intercept the URLs.

Found by investigating various ideas in comments.

Answer (score 96):

> Springfox 3.0.0 only works with Spring Boot <= 2.6.0-M2 but not with versions above it

> [Options for Spring Boot 2.6 M2 <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70036953/springboot-2-6-0-spring-fox-3-failed-to-start-bean-documentationpluginsboot) 
>  1. spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ANT_PATH_MATCHER #-> App.properties 
>      -    But without Actuator
>  2. @EnableWebMvc 
>  3. Migrate to [`springdoc-openapi-ui`](https://springdoc.org/index.html#migrating-from-springfox) - same steps as io.springfox >= 3.X

| ### io.springfox >= 2.X | ### io.springfox >= 3.X |
| --- | --- |
| ``` <dependency> <groupId>io.springfox</groupId> <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId> <version>2.9.2</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>io.springfox</groupId> <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId> <version>2.9.2</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>io.springfox</groupId> <artifactId>springfox-schema</artifactId> <version>2.9.2</version> </dependency> ``` | ``` <dependency> <groupId>io.springfox</groupId> <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId> <version>3.0.0</version> </dependency> ``` |
| browser URL ``` http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html ``` | browser URL ``` http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/ ``` ``` http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html ``` |
| Must Need #### `mvn clean` | Must Need #### `mvn clean` |
| ``` @Configuration @EnableSwagger2 ``` | ``` @Configuration @EnableSwagger2 ``` |

[image]

Comment: `@EnableSwagger2` is not required for version 3+. They recommend to delete that annotation .  "Remove any @EnableSwagger2... annotations" - https://github.com/springfox/springfox

Answer (score 34):

I tried most of these answers and the final solution was creeping..

The right URL is the following

http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/

I'm using Springfox swagger-ui 3.x.x

Refer for complete swagger setup:
http://muralitechblog.com/swagger-rest-api-dcoumentation-for-spring-boot/

Comment: The `/` at the end is the very important part

Comment: OMFG this is unbelievable. My entire weekend wasted over this. Thank you for this solution.

Comment: Adding / at the end of url for swagger-ui worked for me.

Comment: It isn't working for me. Still getting 401. Basically, when I try to enter localhost:8080 it asks for username and password which is very weird. I can only use postman to check things but not url.

Comment: @HuserB1989 maybe Spring Security is enabled. you can remove the dependency and try

Answer (score 29):

Already a lot of answers have stated the right answer but still, there has been some confusion regarding the error.

If you are using Spring Boot Version >= 2.2, it is recommended to use SpringFox Swagger version 3.0.0

Now, only a single dependency is required to be added in the pom.xml.

```
<!-- Swagger dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Once the application is started, **you can get the documentation by hitting either of the new swagger URLs**.

Option 1:
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/

Option 2:
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much. This saved my day. I was entering URL as "http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui" and couldn't get the UI but with "/" at the end, it rendered like magic. Could you plz explain this "/" at the end? Is it mandatory?

Comment: Glad that you found this useful. Yes, with the new release, the "/" at the end is mandatory. You can refer to this blog as well: https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

Comment: This didn't work for me at the first place. but it worked after few try. I have no clue why. I'm facing the same issue after following the tutorial on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gduKpLW_vdY&t=918s&ab_channel=JavaBrains. one of the comments used this method to resolve the same issue.

Comment: Thats fixed it for me, I also reomoved the old swagger dependencies. Thanks !

    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:${swaggerVersion}")
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:${swaggerVersion}")

Answer (score 9):

For Spring Version >= 2.2, you should add the dependency springfox-boot-starter

**pom.xml:**

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <io.springfox.version>3.0.0</io.springfox.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${io.springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${io.springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId>
        <version>${io.springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
        <version>${io.springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${io.springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**ApplicationSwaggerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class ApplicationSwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket employeeApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

}
```

**Swagger-UI link:** http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html#/

Answer (score 4):

For version 3.0.0 only one dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After that you can access the swagger-ui on:

- `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/#`
- `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html`

for version 2.x.x

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${io.springfox.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${io.springfox.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Access the swagger-ui on: `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui`

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to combine Swagger `@Configuration` class with `@EnableWebMvc` class in a **single** file.

**NOT WORKING:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION** was to make it in 2 separate java classes like in docs:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me fix it after a lot of time spent

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this and the issue was that we had a controller without path mapping (thus mapping to "/"). That was blocking the requests to the swagger-ui resources.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring Boot Version >= 2.2, I recommend using SpringFox Swagger version 3.0.0. Keep your pom.xml dependency configuration like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Keep your Swagger configuration class like below:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

public static final Contact DEFAULT_CONTACT = new Contact(
        "Sample App", "http://www.sample.com", "sample@gmail.com");

public static final ApiInfo DEFAULT_API_INFO = new ApiInfo(
        "Awesome API Title", "Awesome API Description", "1.0",
        "urn:tos", DEFAULT_CONTACT,
        "Apache 2.0", "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0", Arrays.asList());

private static final Set<String> DEFAULT_PRODUCES_AND_CONSUMES =
        new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("application/json",
                "application/xml"));

@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .apiInfo(DEFAULT_API_INFO)
            .produces(DEFAULT_PRODUCES_AND_CONSUMES)
            .consumes(DEFAULT_PRODUCES_AND_CONSUMES);
 }
}
```

Now, access your swagger UI by going to this URL: http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html#/

Comment: worked for me with url `localhost:8181/<base-path>/swagger-ui/index.html`

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem recently

http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/ - didn't work

http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html - worked fine

...at the end the issue was caused by some mess in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I deleted the first two dependencies, so only springfox-boot-starter left
and after couple of maven cleanups and restarting the app the first path started to work fine as well
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/

Answer (score 1):

io.springfox >= 3, and using SpringSecurity also

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

SpringFoxConfig Class

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .apiInfo(getApiInfo());
}

private ApiInfo getApiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfo(
            "company_name",
            "message here",
            "VERSION_1",
            "TERMS OF SERVICE URL",
            new Contact("company", "url", "EMAIL"),
            "LICENSE",
            "LICENSE URL",
            Collections.emptyList()
      );
     }
   }
```

WebConfig Class (Make sure **@EnableWebMvc** annotation is not used else you will run into error)

```
   @Configuration
  //@EnableWebMvc
   public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", 
           "OPTIONS");
        }
      }
```

SecurityConfiguration class

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
        // -- Swagger UI v2
        "/v2/api-docs",
        "/swagger-resources",
        "/swagger-resources/**",
        "/configuration/ui",
        "/configuration/**",
        "/configuration/security",
        "/swagger-ui.html",
        "/webjars/**",
        // -- Swagger UI v3 (OpenAPI)
        "/v3/api-docs/**",
        "/swagger-ui/**",
        "/swagger-ui/",
        "/swagger-ui"
        // other public endpoints of your API may be appended to this array

        @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
    httpSecurity.cors();
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
    httpSecurity.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

                httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, 
                             UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
         }
     };
```

Comment: I have done all these steps still swagger is showing 404

Answer (score 0):

Adding `@RequestMapping("/")` in controller level(after `@RestController\@Controller` annotation) helps me to get rid of the `Request method 'GET' not supported` issue. [Thanks to Dhermanns's suggestion](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1672#issuecomment-319957959)

Answer (score 0):

Add `@RequestMapping("/")` at the controller level, It works.

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion: I find there are no jar files under maven repository `${user_home}/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger-ui/2.9.2`,after below steps everything is ok.

I solved this issue by follow steps:

- go to `${user_home}/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger-ui/2.9.2`
- examine whether the files under 2.9.2 is complete。if there are missing files,delete the whole 2.9.2 directory
- execute `reimport all maven projects` in intellij idea

My spring boot version is 2.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

I got swagger issue /swagger-ui.html request method 'get' not supported\request method 'get' not supported.\supported methods post

I was able to fix the issue

In my controller api @RequestMapping() doesn't have path info. provided path like below Fix - @RequestMapping(value = '/v1/createAnalytic')

Answer (score 0):

if You use **Version - V3 || io.springfox >= 3.0.0**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Java code

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2

public class SwaggerConfig {

@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("Your Controller package name"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
}
```

}

V3 browser URL -> `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/#/`
**Run (Must need) : Mvn clean**

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your IDE.

After trying many of these suggestions and still not having any luck, I came across this blog post: https://medium.com/swlh/openapi-swagger-ui-codegen-with-spring-boot-1afb1c0a570e

Where the author stated, "Note: If you are getting Whitelabel Error Page try to restart your IDE and run the project again."

This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This comment saved a lot of my time. In short - I found that someone in my project added mapping to controller like this:

```
@RestController("/api/test")
```

but of course it should look like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
```

Because of above I got 405 responses while trying to see swagger-ui.

@RestConroller's docs explain the issue more precisely:

> The value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component name, to
> be turned into a Spring bean in case of an autodetected component.
> Returns: the suggested component name, if any (or empty String
> otherwise) Since: 4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Version 3.0 you also have to change DocumentationType to **OAS_30** in the Docket Constructor:

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
  return new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30)
                           .select()
                           .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                           .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                           .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it turned out to be an issue because of existing APIs

I had an `Existing API` at controller which was like

`http://localhost:8080/{PathParam}`

I changed it to

`http://localhost:8080/domain/{PathParam}`

and the issue was resolved !!!

Answer (score 0):

Had to do 2 things to fix it:

1. added the below dependency and removed other swagger dependencies

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
       <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. org.springframework.security dependency in pom.xml was blocking the swagger-ui, so added below code to bypass security for swagger UI:

   ```
    @Configuration
    public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                                       "/swagger-resources/**",
                                       "/swagger-ui/**");
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I simply reloaded my maven and it had worked for me
**I have the following dependencies in my POM file.**
`

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.7.4
 

com.example
demo
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
demo
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>1.8</java.version>

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.29</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is likely very bespoke. For some reason running the app via IntelliJ, though I included spring-boot-starter-web in the pom.xml, Tomcat was not starting.

The solution was **running the application via Maven**:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

started Tomcat and all of a sudden http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html was active and working.

Answer (score 0):

i just removed `@EnableSwagger2` and it worked