# swagger-ui not loading with springboot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-2.0

Hi i'm using springboot 1.5.3.RELEASE with swagger2.
When i run app and i can access the json swagger response by accessing "localhost:3030/v2/api-docs" . But i cannot access "localhost:3030/swagger-ui.html" also showing no mapping found for "/swagger-ui.html" .
How do i solve this issue.

**dependencies**

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- mock testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- /mock testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
            <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

**swagger config**

```
@Configuration
@Component
@EnableSwagger2
public class RestConfig {

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter =
                new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public ErpAppConfig configureErpApp() {
        // just to process the @PostConstruct
        return new ErpAppConfig();
    }

      @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Add ResourceHandler such as  `registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
  registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");`

Comment: where should i add this registry???

Comment: a file which extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` In that  override existing method `addResourceHandlers`  for your ref: http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

Comment: Duplicate : Check Answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151540/added-springfox-swagger-ui-and-its-not-working-what-am-i-missing/64333853#64333853

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Added Springfox Swagger-UI and it's not working, what am I missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151540/added-springfox-swagger-ui-and-its-not-working-what-am-i-missing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a mapping for Swagger by override existing method addResourceHandler

```
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");  
       registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

Comment: Also i added permit url in spring security for swagger URL

Comment: Slightly different solution worked for me, also calling parent method: `super.addResourceHandlers(registry);`, check: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2037