# The method is not allowed in Swagger UI after adding the controller

Tags: java, spring, swagger

I have Swagger added to the project and it works https://zapodaj.net/217c8a0dcf348.png.html. After adding the controller

```
@RestController(value = "/register")
public class RegisterRestController {
...

@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public
ResponseEntity<Void> register(
        @RequestBody final RegisterDto registerDTO
) {
    this.userService.createUser(registerDTO);

    final HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(httpHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
}
```

Swagger UI stops working https://zapodaj.net/c60c3029b0905.png.html. Kicks

```
"error": "Method Not Allowed",
"message": "Request method 'GET' not supported",
"status": "405"
```

I found a similar thread on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151540/added-springfox-swagger-ui-and-its-not-working-what-am-i-missing), but I do not know how he can help me. What's up with this Swagger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a mapping to the method I added `"/register"`

```
@PostMapping("/register")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public
ResponseEntity<Void> register(
    @RequestBody final RegisterDto registerDTO
)
```

Comment: remove `@RestController(value = "/register")` from the top