# Swagger UI page is found for Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, http-status-code-404, spring-boot-2

Using Spring Boot `2.3.1`.

Here is a snippet from `pom`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Where swagger version is [last for now](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui): `3.0.0`.

Swagger configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Docket swaggerApiDocket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.demo.controller"))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiDetails());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiDetails() {
        return new ApiInfo("Carpark Controller API",
                "Carpark Service for managing car parks",
                "0.0.1",
                "",
                new springfox.documentation.service.Contact("Jan",
                        "www.demo.com",
                        ""),
                "API License",
                "",
                Collections.emptyList());
    }
}
```

No Security configuration is added. No any `server-path` or some additional configuration.

When the application is up swagger JSON documentation is available:

```
http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs
```

However, if to navigate to swagger UI:

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
```

The result will be:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

Tried to downgrade swagger version to `2.9.2` result is the same.

***How to solve this issue?***

Comment: For latest(Jan 21) configuration with V2 and V3 check - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64333853/410439

Comment: @RaviParekh have a look at the answers. This is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found solution for Spring Boot 2:**

1. Get read from all other swagger dependencies from pom file. Only add next one:

   ```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Swagger configuration could be the same as it was before with `@EnableSwagger2`.

2. Start the application.
3. Swagger UI page is different now:

   http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

Finally, it works!

---

Looking for a solution at the web for this issue found the [following comment](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3070#issuecomment-650591154).

Saw the latest samples for Spring Boot version: [BootWebmvcApplication](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-demos/blob/master/boot-webmvc/src/main/java/io/springfox/demo/bootwebmvc/BootWebmvcApplication.java)

And [build.gradle configuration](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-demos/blob/master/boot-webmvc/build.gradle) for it.

Here is a link to [other projects sources](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-demos).

Comment: It does not work for me ... Still only having the "v2/api-docs" endpoint without the swagger UI.

Comment: ... Hum, it seems there are compatibility problems between Swagger 2 and Spring boot 2 : https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3052

Comment: Versions are compatible for spring boot at question and springfox as answer

Answer (score 0):

In POM.XML file you missed one dependency that has swagger starter

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
<artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Version for this dependency is mandatory it wouldn't work without it.